# AndroidX worker is being canceled when i exit my screen

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-workmanager

Using this library "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0" to run a background thread.
But **OneTimeWorkRequest** is being cancelled everything i exit the screen. What i am trying to acheive is set it run on the application level can someone help please or some hints? here is my code below :

```
            var workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext())
            val data: Data.Builder = Data.Builder().apply {
                putLong("inspectionId", id)
            }
            val task = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NewSyncWorkManager::class.java).apply {
//                setConstraints(constraints)

                setInputData(data.build())
                setInitialDelay(1,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                addTag(id.toString())
            }.build()
            workManager.enqueue(task)
```

while NewSyncWorkManager is as following:

```
class NewSyncWorkManager(context: Context,workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
        override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
                   
                    showNotification()
            
                    val foregroundInfo = ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification!!)
                    setForeground(foregroundInfo)
                    
                    if (inspectionId == 0L) {
                        Log.d("wah", "inspectionId to upload is missing, stopping")
                        return Result.failure()
                    }
            
                    val propertySections = sectionsRepo.getPropertyLayout(inspectionId)?.reportSections 
                    .....
                    UPLOAD requests to the server
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by running the `UPLOAD requests to the server` inside a GlobalScope